# postgres query with regular expression POSIX

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a table which contains three field ip_address,contary_name,region_name.

```
         ip_address         countary_name      region_name
         100.12.34.19           xyz               jk                 
         100.12.34.23           xyz               jk
         170.63.34.41           abc               mn
         170.63.34.42           abc               mn
         170.63.34.43           abc               mn
```

so i need some query like this :

```
select distinct substring('rex_exp') as common_ip,
       substring('rex_exp') as ip_part,countary_name,region_name
  from table;
```

and output is

```
         common_ip      ip_part        countary_name      region_name
         100.12.34.     19,23           xyz               jk                 
         170.63.34.     41,42,43        abc               mn
```

Comment: What datatype is `ip_address`? Is that a varchar/text column or an `inet` type?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: these all are of character varying type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming ip_address is of type text (or varchar) then this should do it:

```
select common_ip,
       string_agg(ip_part, ',')
       country_name,
       region_name
from (
  select substring(ip_address from '[0-9]{2,3}\.[0-9]{2,3}\.[0-9]{2,3}') as common_ip,
         substring(ip_address from '[0-9]{2,3}$') as ip_part,
         country_name, 
         region_name
  from some_table
) t
group by common_ip, country_name, region_name;
```

For old Postgres versions you can replace string_agg with a combination of array_agg and array_to_string

```
select common_ip,
       array_to_string(array_agg(ip_part), ',')
       country_name,
       region_name
from (
  select substring(ip_address from '[0-9]{2,3}\.[0-9]{2,3}\.[0-9]{2,3}') as common_ip,
         substring(ip_address from '[0-9]{2,3}$') as ip_part,
         country_name, 
         region_name
  from some_table
) t
group by common_ip, country_name, region_name;
```

Comment: this query throwing error : function string_agg(text, unknown) does not exist.  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: I m using Postgres 8.4 so there is no string_agg function.